# Python fcntl struct contents

Tags: python, fcntl

Python `fcntl` module has a function `fcntl` that accepts a struct as and `arg` argument. That struct is undocumented, and seems to be platform dependent. Here is a snipped from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_fcntl.py (full function is lines 20-50):

```py
    elif sys.platform.startswith('gnukfreebsd'):
        lockdata = struct.pack('qqihhi', 0, 0, 0, fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0)
    elif sys.platform in ['hp-uxB', 'unixware7']:
        lockdata = struct.pack('hhlllii', fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    else:
        lockdata = struct.pack('hh'+start_len+'hh', fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Question: how do I know which place stands for which argument? I know that it should contain the `start`, `length` and `whence` values, where do they go?

And also, does that code in `test_fcntl.py` cover all the possible platforms? Where does it come from? How do people know how to compose that struct?